# Area of Intersection between Two Circles

Tags: math, geometry

Given two circles:

- C1 at (`x1`, `y1`) with `radius1`
- C2 at (`x2`, `y2`) with `radius2`

How do you calculate the area of their intersection? All standard math functions (`sin`, `cos`, etc.) are available, of course.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Thanks. I was actually aware of the link before posting. I was actually looking for a specific equation using the variables I listed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Okay, using the Wolfram link and Misnomer's cue to look at equation 14, I have derived the following Java solution using the variables I listed and the distance between the centers (which can trivially be derived from them):

```java
double r = radius1;
double R = radius2;
double d = distance;
if(R < r){
    // swap
    r = radius2;
    R = radius1;
}
double part1 = r*r*Math.acos((d*d + r*r - R*R)/(2*d*r));
double part2 = R*R*Math.acos((d*d + R*R - r*r)/(2*d*R));
double part3 = 0.5*Math.sqrt((-d+r+R)*(d+r-R)*(d-r+R)*(d+r+R));

double intersectionArea = part1 + part2 - part3;
```

Comment: Yeah, I checked there and there is already a thread where the officially up-voted answer is that it is good to come back and answer your own question. But it doesn't seem like most SO users actually follow that policy. No offense to Misnomer and I appreciate him trying to help. But, right now, he has 3 up-votes for giving me a link I already knew about before posting. I have done the hard work of translating the information in that link into code and only have 1 up-vote. I've seen this kind of crowd behavior repeatedly on SO and it baffles me.

Comment: @Chris..did you just downvote my answer because...you wanted yours to have more upvotes..now that baffles me..I won't argue your point..because it is kind of silly according to me...but anyways..please at least drop a comment explaining downvotes next time..

Comment: Hey. No, I downvoted it because genuinely don't think it is the best answer. I think it is incomplete. I appreciate you trying to help. But I'm frustrated by the users of SO promoting incomplete answers and I want the more informative and complete answer to have more votes.

Comment: re: awarding points for self-answers - it makes it too easy to game the system.  And philosophically it makes sense that you should only be rewarded when you provide value to others, not to yourself.

Re: downvoting answers - imho, this should only be done when an answer is wrong or misleading.  An answer that provides useful information, even if it's not exactly what you want, may still be useful to others.

Comment: Also, it might be worth adding explanatory comments (and code) around error conditions and what they mean.  E.g. If (expression in sqrt) < 0 or negative, or -1 < (expression in acos) > 1

Comment: I never said I wanted to reward points to myself. Rather, I wanted to not be _denied_ points, despite the fact that I _am_ providing a greater value to others, simply because I had answered my own question. It is an important distinction.

Comment: @user1145925 With r=1, R=2, d=1, the correct intersection area actually is Pi, not Pi/2.

Comment: @rolve Wow, I think I'm going insane.. Yeah, never mind, this answer is fine.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a JavaScript function that does exactly what Chris was after:

```js
function areaOfIntersection(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
{
    var rr0 = r0 * r0;
    var rr1 = r1 * r1;
    var d = Math.sqrt((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0) + (y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0));
    var phi = (Math.acos((rr0 + (d * d) - rr1) / (2 * r0 * d))) * 2;
    var theta = (Math.acos((rr1 + (d * d) - rr0) / (2 * r1 * d))) * 2;
    var area1 = 0.5 * theta * rr1 - 0.5 * rr1 * Math.sin(theta);
    var area2 = 0.5 * phi * rr0 - 0.5 * rr0 * Math.sin(phi);
    return area1 + area2;
}
```

However, this method will return NaN if one circle is completely inside the other, or they are not touching at all. A slightly different version that doesn't fail in these conditions is as follows:

```js
function areaOfIntersection(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
{
    var rr0 = r0 * r0;
    var rr1 = r1 * r1;
    var d = Math.sqrt((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0) + (y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0));

    // Circles do not overlap
    if (d > r1 + r0)
    {
    return 0;
    }

    // Circle1 is completely inside circle0
    else if (d <= Math.abs(r0 - r1) && r0 >= r1)
    {
    // Return area of circle1
    return Math.PI * rr1;
    }

    // Circle0 is completely inside circle1
    else if (d <= Math.abs(r0 - r1) && r0 < r1)
    {
    // Return area of circle0
    return Math.PI * rr0;
    }

    // Circles partially overlap
    else
    {
    var phi = (Math.acos((rr0 + (d * d) - rr1) / (2 * r0 * d))) * 2;
    var theta = (Math.acos((rr1 + (d * d) - rr0) / (2 * r1 * d))) * 2;
    var area1 = 0.5 * theta * rr1 - 0.5 * rr1 * Math.sin(theta);
    var area2 = 0.5 * phi * rr0 - 0.5 * rr0 * Math.sin(phi);
    
    // Return area of intersection
    return area1 + area2;
    }
}
```

I wrote this function by reading the information found at the [Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180422082904/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54785.html). I found this clearer than the [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) explanation.

Comment: Thanks - it did help me out! The modified version was exactly what I was after.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I'm not completely sure where the logical bug is, but it fails for at least these cases (when r1 approaches 2 from beneath): x0=0, y0=0, r0=1, x1=1, y0=0, r1=2. Specifically, your code gives the area approaching Pi, when it should be approaching Pi/2.

Comment: @user1145925, For inputs x0=0, y0=0, r0=1, x1=1, y0=0, r1=2 an output of Pi is correct as circle 0 has an area of Pi, and is entirely contained within circle 2.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to check out this [analytical solution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) and apply the formula with your input values.

Another Formula is given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180422082904/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54785.html) for when the radii are equal:

```
Area = r^2*(q - sin(q))  where q = 2*acos(c/2r),
where c = distance between centers and r is the common radius.
```

Comment: +1 First link has full derivation of the formula. The second one is useful if the radii of the circles are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Is there a more general formula that can be derived using specifically the variables I gave (e.g. not assuming a common radius)?

Comment: It think the first link eq 14 gives you a general solution but I need to brush up maths to see what exactly is happening...also you might need more need more than radii of circles to find this also try this if helpful-http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/GeometryConicSectionCircleIntersection.aspx

Comment: Okay. I was hoping that there was a straightforward equation using the variables I listed. I'll try to look into eq 14 and find a way to substitute the variables I had into it.

Answer (score 2):

Here here i was making character generation tool, based on circle intersections... you may find it useful.

with dynamically provided circles:

```
    C: {
        C1: {id: 'C1',x:105,y:357,r:100,color:'red'},
        C2: {id: 'C2',x:137,y:281,r:50, color:'lime'},
        C3: {id: 'C3',x:212,y:270,r:75, color:'#00BCD4'}
    },
```

Check FULL fiddle...
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/5skpoarn/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in Python.

```py
"""Intersection area of two circles"""

import math
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple


@dataclass
class Circle:
    x: float
    y: float
    r: float

    @property
    def coord(self):
        return self.x, self.y


def find_intersection(c1: Circle, c2: Circle) -> float:
    """Finds intersection area of two circles.

    Returns intersection area of two circles otherwise 0
    """

    d = math.dist(c1.coord, c2.coord)
    rad1sqr = c1.r ** 2
    rad2sqr = c2.r ** 2

    if d == 0:
        # the circle centers are the same
        return math.pi * min(c1.r, c2.r) ** 2

    angle1 = (rad1sqr + d ** 2 - rad2sqr) / (2 * c1.r * d)
    angle2 = (rad2sqr + d ** 2 - rad1sqr) / (2 * c2.r * d)

    # check if the circles are overlapping
    if (-1 <= angle1 < 1) or (-1 <= angle2 < 1):
        theta1 = math.acos(angle1) * 2
        theta2 = math.acos(angle2) * 2

        area1 = (0.5 * theta2 * rad2sqr) - (0.5 * rad2sqr * math.sin(theta2))
        area2 = (0.5 * theta1 * rad1sqr) - (0.5 * rad1sqr * math.sin(theta1))

        return area1 + area2
    elif angle1 < -1 or angle2 < -1:
        # Smaller circle is completely inside the largest circle.
        # Intersection area will be area of smaller circle
        # return area(c1_r), area(c2_r)
        return math.pi * min(c1.r, c2.r) ** 2
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    @dataclass
    class Test:
        data: Tuple[Circle, Circle]
        expected: float

    tests = [
        Test((Circle(2, 4, 2), Circle(3, 9, 3)), 0),
        Test((Circle(0, 0, 2), Circle(-1, 1, 2)), 7.0297),
        Test((Circle(1, 3, 2), Circle(1, 3, 2.19)), 12.5664),
        Test((Circle(0, 0, 2), Circle(-1, 0, 2)), 8.6084),
        Test((Circle(4, 3, 2), Circle(2.5, 3.5, 1.4)), 3.7536),
        Test((Circle(3, 3, 3), Circle(2, 2, 1)), 3.1416)
    ]

    for test in tests:
        result = find_intersection(*test.data)
        assert math.isclose(result, test.expected, rel_tol=1e-4), f"{test=}, {result=}"

    print("PASSED!!!")
```